# Comparing Generics in Java

Tags: java, templates

If I have a class that uses a template `<T>` how do I compare two variables of type T? One of my friends told me that you should add `<T extends Comparable<? super T>>` to your class in order to compare type T variables, but I dont competely understand what he ment. Here is my class:

```
public class SomeClass<T extends Comparable<? super T>>
{
    public SomeClass(){}

    public T foo(T par, T value)
    {
        if(value > par)
        {
            return value
        }
        else
        {
            return par;
        }
    }
}
```

And in my Main.java:

```
SomeClass<Integer> sc = new SomeClass<Integer>();
Integer val1 = 10;
Integer val2 = 5;
System.out.println(sc.foo(val1, val2));
```

The error i get is:

```
error: bad operand types for binary operator '>' if(value > par)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `T` implements [`Comparable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html), so you should use its [`compareTo()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html#compareTo(T)) method.

```
if (value.compareTo(par) > 0) {
   ....
}
```

Also, note that in java it is called *Generics*, and not *Templates*, and is quite different from C++ templates (much weaker and much less complicated from the C++ version). One important difference is it does not work on primitives, only on objects - so if you wanted to use `SomeClass<int>` - that's impossible. (You could use `SomeClass<Integer>` however).

Also note, you cannot assign

```
T = 0;
```

Since `T` is an object.

Comment: The compareTo(par) worked. And thanks for the tip I only started Java last week. And the `T = 0` thing was a mistake, will fix it in the code.

Answer (score 2):

`>` operator can be used only on primitives and not on objects. You need to use `compareTo` method for comparing objects.